# devise ldap authentication just gives invalid username or password error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ldap

I have followed the tutorials found in the devise ldap github site. When I try to login I get this in the log:

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at Tue Feb 05 11:37:04 -0500 2013
  Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"Cl2fTO6guIUMNVCV2+TXSZRNR56RFqiAurbicwyfito=",    "commit"=>"Sign in", "user"=>{"remember_me"=>"0", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "login"=>"jchoi"}, "utf8"=>"���"}
  SQL (7.9ms)   SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc,    a.attnotnull
  FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
  ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
  WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
  AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
  ORDER BY a.attnum

   User Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."login" = 'jchoi' LIMIT 1
   SQL (3.4ms)   SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc, a.attnotnull
   FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
   ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
   WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
   AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
   ORDER BY a.attnum

    LDAP: LDAP dn lookup: =jchoi
    LDAP: LDAP search for login: =jchoi
    LDAP: Authorizing user =jchoi,ou=Root,dc=complay,dc=com
    LDAP: LDAP dn lookup: =jchoi
    LDAP: LDAP search for login: =jchoi
    Completed   in 53ms
     Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
     Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"Cl2fTO6guIUMNVCV2+TXSZRNR56RFqiAurbicwyfito=", "commit"=>"Sign in", "user"=>{"remember_me"=>"0", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "login"=>"jchoi"}, "utf8"=>"���"}
     Rendered devise/shared/_links.erb (1.6ms)
     Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (13.8ms)
     Completed 200 OK in 23ms (Views: 20.7ms | ActiveRecord
```

does this mean that ldap connection went through and something is wrong with my ruby code or is it not being able to access and check my username and password and is just throwing an invalid username and password error?

Thank you

Comment: yes. I have found it a while ago. Apparently I didnt setup the LDAP connection properly with the server and the server was unable to get the connection properly